# How to filter a query with a string ignoring it's lowercase or uppercase?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a query for filtering with an input.
It's working but I want to filter by ignoring lower or capital cases.

For example:

input> test --> output listing
but when I enter
input> Test -->no output

I want to get output in any cases.
Here is my query

```
alerts = Event.objects.filter(process_type__reporting_group__option__contains=group_search_bar)
```

Comment: change that __contains to __icontains

Read more about it: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#icontains